# Pass this to callback

Tags: javascript

I know what the problem is but not sure what's the best option to solve this issue. I have got a callback and I'm not able to access `this` from it. I don't want to have any variable outside the scope to refer this. Can I pass `this` as a parameter?

```
    var myModule = Module.create({

           init: function() {
                ws.subscribe('/topic/notifications', this._wsNotifications, headers);
           },

            refresh: function() {
            },

            _wsNotifications: function ( message ) {
                 this.refresh();  //Error: 'this' is undefined because it's a callback
             }
        });
```

Comment: Of course you can, have you tried it?

Comment: Why would you not want a variable outside of the scope of the callback to hold a reference to this?  It's a perfectly acceptable practice.

Comment: Use `myModule.refresh(); `

Comment: @davidkonrad That could be good advice, but you also would doom that module to only be able to serve `myModule`, hardcoding it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can solve this is using [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) at the source When you specify the callback do

```
  ws.subscribe('/topic/notifications', this._wsNotifications.bind(this), headers);
```

or cache the `this` to a variable.

```
 var myModule = Module.create({
       self  : this,
       init: function() {
            ws.subscribe('/topic/notifications', this._wsNotifications, headers);
       },

        refresh: function() {
        },

        _wsNotifications: function ( message ) {
             self.refresh();  //Error: 'this' is undefined because it's a callback
         }
    });
```

Comment: Is bind supported in IE7?

Comment: @RuntimeException. No. You can add a shim as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Check the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @RuntimeException what are you using for module.create?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of ECMAscript's [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) `Function.prototype.bind`.

```
init: function() {
            ws.subscribe('/topic/notifications', this._wsNotifications.bind(this), headers);
       },
```

Now, `this` within `_wsNotifications` will refer to the object you bound it to.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try.

```
var myModule = Module.create({

       var self = this;

       init: function() {
            ws.subscribe('/topic/notifications', this._wsNotifications, headers);
       },

        refresh: function() {
        },

        _wsNotifications: function ( message ) {
           self.refresh();  //Error: 'this' is undefined because it's a callback
        }

    });

    return interactions;
});
```

note the creation and use of the `self` variable instead of the `this` variable. Using this method will preserve `this`, even when it would normally change scope.